# Fastest storage for virtual memory

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

I want to know which is the fastest storage medium like hd,
fd, sd card.... to be used as virtual memory as my RAM is only 1GB and I didn`t want to spend too much on purchasing a new one.

Comment: SSDs are faster than hard drives, and RAM is relatively cheap now. I'd recommend buying RAM sooner than storage, though. There's no competition with speed there.

Answer (score 3):

If you are low on memory, there is *nothing* better than adding more RAM.  Since RAM is so cheap, there is no reason not to get it.  [Crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/index.aspx) has a great memory advisor tool that can help you select the right memory.  Their prices are good, but you can get better deals out there.

As for the other mediums, its impossible to say for sure.  Paging memory requires both reading and writing to a medium.  And every medium has different read and write speeds.  Their ability will vary based on their specs, as well as your machines specs.

Comment: OK, I will purchase a RAM rather than purchasing a storage medium. But, the main reason for posting the question is that I want to get !dea of speed of different storages when used as virtual memory.

Comment: To answer that question, the best thing would be a SSD.  However, SSDs come in different flavors.  Generally speaking the newer the better.